# Webview is loading but not showing

Tags: javascript, android

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function Character1(canvas, progress, duration, delay) {
        console.log("c1 " + progress);

        delay = delay || 1;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        debugger;

        if (progress < duration) {

            canvas.strokeStyle = "black";
            ctx.beginPath();
     //ctx.moveTo(3, 1);//original forum code 
            //ctx.lineTo(3, 15 * ((progress + 1)/duration));
     ctx.moveTo(2, 1);
            ctx.lineTo(2 , 20* ((progress + 1) / duration));
           // ctx.moveTo(1, 13);
           // ctx.lineTo(1 , 30* ((progress + 1) / duration));
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath()

            setTimeout(function () {
                Character1(canvas, progress + 1, duration, delay);
            }, delay);

        } else {
            debugger;
            $(document.body).trigger("Character1Completed");
        }
    }

    function Character2(canvas, progress, duration, delay) {
        console.log("c2");

        delay = delay || 1;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        if (progress < duration) {
            canvas.strokeStyle = "black";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(5, 20);//Decrease the 2nd value to move line upwards
            ctx.lineTo(30 * ((progress + 1) / duration), 20);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath()

            setTimeout(function () {
                Character2(canvas, progress + 1, duration, delay);
            }, delay);
        }
        else {
            
            $(document.body).trigger("Character2Completed");
        }
    }

    function Character3(canvas, progress, duration, delay) {
        console.log("c3");

        delay = delay || 1;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        if (progress < duration) {

            var x = 23;//Decrease/increase to move the arc right/left side
            var y = 12;//Decrease to move the arc up
            var radius = 10;
            var startAngle = .3 * Math.PI;
            var endAngle = -1.3 * Math.PI;
            var counterClockwise = false;

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle * ((progress + 1) / duration), true);
            ctx.lineWidth = 1;
            ctx.stroke();

            setTimeout(function () {
                Character3(canvas, progress + 1, duration, delay);
            }, delay);
        }
        else {
            $(document.body).trigger("Character3Completed");
        }
    }

    $(document.body).on("Character1Completed", function (e) {
        console.log("Starting Character 2");

        Character2(canvas, 0, 30, 33);
    });

  /*  $(document.body).on("Character2Completed", function (e) {
        console.log("Starting Character 3");

        Character3(canvas, 0, 30, 33);
    });*/

    $(document.body).on("Character3Completed", function (e) {
        console.log("Completed Drawing!");
    });

    // Start Drawing
    Character1(canvas, 0, 30, 33);

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is my HTML code. When i am trying to load in android

```
            WebView wv;  
            wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mybrowser1);  
            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/ta.html");
            wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

It is loading the url, but is not visible.
I don't know whether the following is any error:

> In ResourceHandle::create newHandle -> Blocked Failure

In logcat it is giving like this. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

While trying to display the webpage directly without any button click,it is not displaying the image. Instead it is showing

> your browser does not support the html5 canvas tag

Comment: You need to know when your webview is ready to start doing javascript. I don't know much on Android but there is maybe an event to send.
Also, maybe you need to turn on an option in your Manifest in order to run canvas stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot to include this permission. Now it is working.                                                                                   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Answer (score 0):

I used this settings and you html page, it works fine.
here is the result:
[image]

```
 WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebViewClient wvClient = new WebViewClient();
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(wvClient);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.42/test");
```